# ReactJs Redux Firestore Cors policy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

In my ReactJs app I use Firestore with redux.Every time when I make request cloudstore throw exeption for the corse policy this is if I make it from chrome browser.In firefox I have corse rules and there the request goes through.The exeption throwns on the firestore.collection()

```
firestore
        .collection('orders')
        .add({
            ...order,
        })
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS', order });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_ORDER_ERROR', err });
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with Google Chrome. You can check this [answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11089651?hl=en&msgid=11328844) which mentions the following:

> chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors
>
> Disable the 'out-of-blink-cors' flag by copying and pasting that address into the address bar of Chrome followed by [enter]. In the page that opens you'll see a highlighted so-called 'flag' (experiment). Disable it and restart Chrome
>   (Edit: previously I said to enable the flag but only disabling seems to work)
>
> In many cases that solves the issue, for now but you may want to read on:
>
> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is subject of change in Chrome version 76. New headers are introduced as part of security and those must handled in the code. Later the CORS requests of extensions must be handled in background pages rather then content scripts.
>   Read all about the recommended actions (for developers) and further restrictions on this page of Google:
>   [Changes to Cross-Origin Requests in Chrome Extension Content Scripts](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/)

So, disabling this could help.